# How to set password and key event condition in js?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

How to set double condition in javascript?

My code is not working. With correct password, window.location dont work

```js
var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validate() {

  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  if (password == "ad" && event.keyCode === 13) {
    window.location = "https://pac.com/arias"; // Redirecting to other page.
    return false;
  } else {
    attempt--; // Decrementing by one.
    alert("Contraseña incorrecta. Inténtalo de nuevo!");
    // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
    if (attempt == 0) {

      document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

only one condition is working, but not both conditions...¿What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `...  && event.keyCode === 13`? What event? Also, from the URL in the code, this looks like it might be intended to run on a public site. Please be aware that in terms of security, this is about as weak as it gets.

Comment: Also please update the snippet with HTML and remember to click tidy before saving

Comment: its only for demo work. I suppose php to handle real security. thanks

Comment: Also if you use the submit event, you do not need to test for enter

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the poor security, you want to study this

```js
var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
// Below function Executes on submit
  document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    if (document.getElementById("password").value.trim() !== "ad") {
      e.preventDefault();
      attempt--; // Decrementing by one.
      alert("Contraseña incorrecta."+(attempt>0?" Inténtalo de nuevo!":""));
      // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
      document.getElementById("password").disabled = attempt <= 0
      document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = attempt <= 0
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form id="login" action="https://pac.com/arias">
  pw: <input type="password" id="password" />
  <input type="submit" id="submitButton" />
</form>
```